# footer doesn't extend all the way to the right edge of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal: I am trying to implement a CSS footer as described [on this page](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx).

Problem: The footer doesn't touch the right edge of the page.

I have stripped down my page to the following simplest case that still exhibits this problem:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>



<div class="row footer">
</div> <!-- end of row footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%; /* the footer needs this */
box-sizing: border-box; 
}


body {
position: relative;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-bottom: 100px; /* the footer needs this */
min-height: 100%; /* the footer needs this */
}

.footer { /* footer trick learned from https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx */
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #eee;
}
```

How can I make the footer extend all the way to the right? At first I thought this was related to Boostrap (which I am using in the "real" version of the page), but that doesn't seem to be the cause.

I have tried adding "padding-right: 0;" to the footer class but it had no effect.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] somewhere.

Comment: so you need text align right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your footer has a `row` class which adds a `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px` to your footer. (It's from Bootstrap) Causing the gap.

You can either add a `left: 15px; right: 15px` to the footer or remove the `row` class.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/vw489p0n/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer {
   margin:0;
}
```

give `margin:0` to your **row footer** class.

or give your `body` to `margin:0`

Answer (score 0):

You almost got this:

Html

```
 <div class="row nopadding">
       <div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
           <div class=" footer">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <!--links-->
                </div><!-- end of col-6-->
               <div class="col-md-6">
                 <!--Contact-->
              </div><!-- end of col-6-->
          </div> <!-- end of footer -->
      </div> <!-- end of col-12-->
 </div> <!-- end of row-->
```

CSS:

```
    html {
    height: 100%; /* the footer needs this */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
    body {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* the footer needs this */
    min-height: 100%; /* the footer needs this */
    margin:0;
    }
    .footer { /* footer trick learned from https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #009688;
    }         
    .nopadding{
     margin:0 !important;
     padding:0 !important;    
     }
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/edfyv1e3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove body padding and add footer css below.

```
body {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 6rem;/* remove padding*/
      min-height: 100%;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    } 
.footer {     
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #efefef;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap, you're running into a little issue. In the Bootstrap docs they're sainy: Always wrap your `row` elements inside a `container`. This has to be done because the `row` class adds a margin to it's childs. To avoid (or let's say negate) that, you need to wrap them in a `container`.

So your markup should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row footer">
  </div>
  <!-- end of row footer -->
</div>
```

There isn't any other modification necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually User agent is applying some margin to the body by default, so if you remove that margin by adding margin attribute to body will resolve this. Please refer the below css

```
body {
position: relative;
padding-top: 80px;
margin : 0px;
padding-bottom: 100px; /* the footer needs this */
min-height: 100%; /* the footer needs this */
}
```